# Rails/ActiveRecord queries using hash instead of chained methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

The usual way to do queries is chained methods, such as:

```
Post.where(active: true).select(:id, :title).limit(5)
```

Is there a way to construct this query using a hash instead? i.e. something like:

```
Post.where(
  where: [{active: true}],
  select: [:id, :title],
  limit: 5
)
```

(Various reasons for this, e.g. the hash could be constructed in response to a user query and serialized for processing later on.)

Comment: your user pass params to the controller, then you do the queries dynamically with the params : `Post.where(active: params[:post][:visibility].to_s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom class method on your model to pass query arguments as a big hash and then prepare the chained query using [inject](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject). (You can also use [each_with_object](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) instead if that works for you).

```
class Post
  def self.criteria(options = {})
    options.inject(self) do |out, (k, v)|
      out = out.send(k, v)
      out
    end
  end
end

hash = {
  where: { active: true },
  select: [:id, :title],
  limit: 5
}

Post.criteria(hash)
 => # ActiveRecord Relation for above query
```

If your `where` key has an array of hashes as value as mentioned in your question, then you can convert it to a single hash as:

```
Post.where(foo: 1).where(bar: 2)
```

is same as:

```
Post.where(foo: 1, bar: 2)
```

Do this conversion as below:

```
hash[:where] = hash[:where].each_with_object({}) { |h, out| out.merge!(h) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

**BUT**

There are gems that can help you do that like [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) and [rack-reducer](https://github.com/chrisfrank/rack-reducer)

**OR**

You can always do it yourself.

### Let's start with a very naive approach:

Define a method to get the params that we are interested in:

```
def query_params
  params.slice(:where, :select, :limit) # or make a proper permit call
end
```

Define our basic scoping for this user:

```
def base_scope
  Post.where(whateveryouwant)
end
```

Then you need to loop on these and apply them to our `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
query_params.reduce(base_scope) { |ac, (key, value)| ac.public_send(key, value) }
```